# Working locations the other way round

Tags: xcode, mapkit, core-location

I want to enter a long/lat and to update the MapView to show where I have entered.

There are many excellent examples her about how to use MapKit and CoreLocation to show where you currently are but have been unable to find any that work it the other way round.

Does anyone know of any examples that allow you to enter a long/lat and then display the answer.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simple answer, so maybe that's the reason why you didn't find it. What you need to do is provide a region to your MapView based on the latitude & longitude coordinates.

It would look like this:

```
- (void)centerMapOnLocation:(id)sender{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = ......; // conversion and origin of data left to the reader
    center.longitude = .......; // conversion and origin of data left to the reader
    //Span of the région we want to display
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    //Region you actually want to display
    MKCoordinateRegion aRegion;
    aRegion.center = center;
    aRegion.span = span;

    //Everything 's ready, let's move the map to the right place
    [mapView setRegion:aRegion animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. I've tried something similar but will retest using your explicit example tomorrow.